# AngularJS Controller to update $scope automatically when backend data changes

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, api, rest

I have a Service which uses $http to 'get' some JSON data from a REST API. The Controller uses the Service to get this data and initialise it in the $scope. How can I make it so that every time the JSON API changes that change is updated in the $scope, and thus the view?

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, BuildService) {
    init();
    function init() {
        BuildService.getBuilds().then(function() {
            $scope.builds = BuildService.data();
        });
    }
});
```

Service:

```
app.service('BuildService', function ($http, $q) {

    var BuildService = {}; 

    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var data = [];  

    BuildService.getBuilds = function () {
        //return builds;

        $http.get('/api').
          success(function(d, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            data = d;
            deffered.resolve();

          }).
          error(function(d, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            deffered.reject();
          });

          return deffered.promise;

    };

    BuildService.data = function() { return data; };

    return BuildService;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not AngularJS-specific. What you want to achieve is a real-time app.

### Method 1: polling

Use `$interval` to check JSON API every 30 seconds or so.

### Method 2: WebSocket-based notification

If you have control over the JSON API, you can create another WebSocket-based notification API. Whenever JSON API changes, notify client to fetch JSON API again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you really have too much unneccessary logic. Keep it simple and just go like that. If you want to reuse the GET you can do it in a `getBuilds` controller method.

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http, BuildService) {
    init();
    function init() {
        $http.get('/api').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.builds = data;
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, thats better. But if the data changes how can i make update it the $scope automatically?

Comment: Your data will only change if you do a request. If you want to check your builds you have two options. You can implement polling, that means, you do the same `GET` as in your `init`-function every `x` seconds. Or you take a look into [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which enable you to have a duplex-connection between your page and the server, which enables you to listen on `update now` messages from the server.